# Obtaining measures of effect for contingency tables with multiply imputed data

Tags: effect-size, contingency-tables, multiple-imputation

The `epi.2by2` function in the `epiR` package computes a chi-square test and provides measures of effect when count data are provided in a contingency table.

My dataset has missing values, which have been imputed using `mice`. I have used the `epi.2by2` function to obtain estimates for the **raw** data and am wondering if it is important to conduct the same analyses for the imputed data (i.e., by pooling the results across imputations). To date, I have received mixed advice.

If it is important to repeat the analyses on the imputed data, how would I go about calculating the relevant measures of effect (e.g., odds ratio, relative risk, attributable risk)? The `micombine.chisquare` function in `miceadds` provides a way of pooling chi-square estimates, but measures of effect are not provided.

**Note - these analyses are for descriptive purposes only.**